# Workers with certain strength carrying boxes. (Greedy)

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms

I just had an algorithms exam and had the following problem:
Supposed there are $n$ workers and $n$ objects. Each worker has a strength, $s_i$ and each object has a weight $w_i$. Each worker needs to be assigned to an object, and they can only be assigned to a specific object $w_i$ if $s_i \ge w_i$. There are also $k$ pills. Each worker has the ability to take a pill and increase there strength by 20.

For example:
s = [10, 30, 30]
w = [30, 20, 20]
k = 1

The solution would be to give $s_1$ the pill and assign $w_1$ to $s_1$, $w_2$ to $s_2$ and $w_3$ to $s_3$.

The solution needs to be $O(nlogn)$

My solution is as follows:

```
algorithm(workers, objects, k):
    pills = k
    workers = workers.sort()
    objects = objects.sort()
    for i = 1 to n:
        if w[i] >= s[i]:
            assign(w[i], s[i])
        else if w[i] + 20 >= s[i]:
            pills -= 1
            assign(w[i], s[i])
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

I'm wondering if my algorithm works and if it is the optimal solution. If not could someone explain what is? Thank you!

Comment: You didn't specify what the objective is. Do you just need to decide whether an assignment is possible? Do you need to minimize the number of pills?

Comment: whether its possible

Comment: Something must be missing in your code because you don't use "pills".

Comment: Please don't add clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your question so it is self-contained and contains all relevant information.  Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you try dynamic programming: see https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info.  Please clarify whether a worker can take more than one pill.

Answer (score 1):

I won’t answer your question but tell you about one thing you need to check: Every time you assign a worker or a worker + pill, you waste some amount. Is it possible to get a better outcome by assigning a worker + pill to a task requiring 20 or 19 more strength so nothing of strength is wasted? If yes give an example. If not give a reason why.

I expect things might be interesting if a worker can take more than one pill.